# Why Pessimistic triggers a deadlock

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, deadlock, rdbms, pessimistic-locking

I'm trying to undestand Pessimistic Lock with a simple example of Bank Money Transfer.

I believe this statements can lead to a Deadlock

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance - amount where id = 123;
UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance + amount where id = 456;

COMMIT;
```

And i believe this statements also lead to a Deadlock

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT BankAccount wHERE id = 123 FOR UPDATE; // Statement #1
SELECT BankAccount WHERE id = 456 FOR UPDATE; // Statement #2

// perform some logics

UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance - amount where id = 123;
UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance + amount where id = 456;

COMMIT;
```

This is because if having 2 concurrent transactions T1 and T2, T1 can lock the first account with **Statement #1** and T2 can lock the second account using **Statement #2** which ends with a deadlock (Please correct me if i'm wrong)

Now i've tried the following Transaction, and it also leads to a Deadlock, but i can't see why !

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT BankAccount wHERE id IN (123, 456) FOR UPDATE; // Statement #1

// perform some logics

UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance - amount where id = 123;
UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance + amount where id = 456;

COMMIT;
```

***Notes:***

1. i've tried all these transactions using JDBC in a Java 11 Environnement.
2. I'm using multithreading to simulate concurrent access to the database. Each Money transfer happen by 1 single thread which choose randomly 2 different account and make a money transfer.

Here's the StackTrace:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: deadlock detected
  Détail : Process 6596 waits for ExclusiveLock on tuple (314,24) of relation 321198 of database 321194; blocked by process 6643.
Process 6643 waits for ShareLock on transaction 326566; blocked by process 6637.
Process 6637 waits for ShareLock on transaction 326569; blocked by process 6574.
Process 6574 waits for ExclusiveLock on tuple (314,24) of relation 321198 of database 321194; blocked by process 6596.
  Indice : See server log for query details.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2268)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:313)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:125)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at com.mssmfactory.service.OptimisticMoneyTransferHandler.transfer(OptimisticMoneyTransferHandler.java:76)
    at ConcurrentMoneyTransferHandlerTest.lambda$test$0(ConcurrentMoneyTransferHandlerTest.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Here's my code that transfer money:

```
public class PessimisticMoneyTransferHandler implements IMoneyTransferHandler {

    private IDatabaseConnector iDatabaseConnector;

    public void transfer(Long senderId, Long receiverId, Double amount) throws SQLException, NoSuchBankAccountException, InsufficientBalanceException {
        try (Connection connection = this.iDatabaseConnector.getConnection()) {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mssmbank.mssmbank.bankaccounts WHERE id IN (?, ?) FOR UPDATE");
            preparedStatement.setLong(1, senderId);
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, receiverId);

            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if (resultSet.next()) {
                Long firstAccountId = resultSet.getLong("id");
                Double firstAccountBalance = resultSet.getDouble("balance");

                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    Double secondAccountBalance = resultSet.getDouble("balance");

                    boolean isFirstSender = firstAccountId.equals(senderId);

                    if (isFirstSender && firstAccountBalance < amount) {
                        connection.rollback();

                        throw new InsufficientBalanceException();
                    }
                    else if (!isFirstSender && secondAccountBalance < amount) {
                        connection.rollback();

                        throw new InsufficientBalanceException();
                    }

                    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE mssmbank.mssmbank.bankaccounts SET balance = balance - ? WHERE id = ?");
                    preparedStatement.setDouble(1, amount);
                    preparedStatement.setDouble(2, senderId);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE mssmbank.mssmbank.bankaccounts SET balance = balance + ? WHERE id = ?");
                    preparedStatement.setDouble(1, amount);
                    preparedStatement.setDouble(2, receiverId);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                    connection.commit();
                } else throw new NoSuchBankAccountException(receiverId);
            } else throw new NoSuchBankAccountException(senderId);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the main code:

```
    final int numberOfAccount = 10;
    final int numberOfTransactions = 150;

    List<IBankAccountDetails> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<>(numberOfAccount);
    Runnable transaction = () -> {
        Random random = new Random();

        int emeeterIndex;
        int receiverIndex;

        do {
            emeeterIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfAccount);
            receiverIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfAccount);
        } while (emeeterIndex == receiverIndex);

        IBankAccountDetails emeeterAccount = bankAccounts.get(emeeterIndex);
        IBankAccountDetails receiverAccount = bankAccounts.get(receiverIndex);

        double amount = random.nextInt((int) (1.5 * emeeterAccount.getAccountBalance()));

        try {
            this.iMoneyTransferHandler.transfer(emeeterAccount.getAccountId(), receiverAccount.getAccountId(), amount);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchBankAccountException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InsufficientBalanceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTransactions; i++)
        executorService.execute(transaction);

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you have deadlock or only session waiting on a lock ? Do you have a error message ? if yes what is it ? To describe a locking scenario or a deadlock scenario you need to identifiy database sessions and timing information: please edit you question. For example in your last scenario you cannot have a deadlock or locking scenario because you have only one single session and one single transaction.

Comment: Sorry for few informations. Yes i have a message error. And i didn't mentionne it but i'm simulating multiple access to database using multithreading, each money transaction occurs in 1 single thread. I'll edit my post

Comment: I edited it, please take a look and tell me what's wrong ? if i'm understanding it wrong about pessimistic lock or if i programmed wrongly and a deadlock is happening

Comment: Can you  post PostgreSQL log for the related timeframe ? Can you reproduce the issue ? If yes, could you set `log_statement='all'` just for the test duration and post the log filtered by the process identifiers involved in the deadlock ?

Comment: In general deadlocks occur if same locks are taken in a different order. To avoid deadlock, you coud try to add an ORDER BY clause to SELECT... FOR UPDATE and modify UPDATE ordering to so that the ordering is deterministic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following transaction if run in parallel should not trigger deadlock:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance - amount where id = 123;
UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance + amount where id = 456;
COMMIT;
```

But following transactions if run in parallel can trigger deadlock:

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance - amount where id = 123;
    UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance + amount where id = 456;
    COMMIT;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance - amount where id = 456;
    UPDATE BankAccount SET balance = balance + amount where id = 123;
    COMMIT;
```

In general deadlock occurs when same locks (same objects, same mode) are taken in a different order. In this case it's the exclusive locks on following objects:

- row for id 123 in table bankaccount
- row for id 456 in table bankaccount

In your Java code you generate a lot of transactions for a very small set of accounts by generating the bank account numbers randomly. This increases the risk of locking conflicts and the risk of deadlocks because if several transactions run on same accounts the locks may not be taken in the same order:

- there is no ORDER BY in the SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statement
- the ordering of UPDATE statement is only based on the account role in the transaction and makes possible that two different transactions don't lock the same row in the same order (because in one transaction a given account is the first processed and in another transaction the same account in the last processed).

Comment: You're a genius ! thank you ;) ... no DeadLock with the ORDER BY as well ! and yes i intentionally generated lot of transactions for a very small set of accounts to simulate the concurrent access and force the Deadlock but was missing the ORDER BY right ! one last question, if i change numberOfAccount to 2000 for example and keep the same numberOfTransactions (Less contention) it would be more interresting to use an Optimistic approach right ?

Comment: It depends. You have to take into account what is the goal: faster execution ? less deadlocks or conflicts ? code easier to maintain ? It's possible that optimistic locking is faster but you need to code differently. I think this discussion is also interesting https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=pessimistic-locking-vs-optimistic-locking (even if this for Oracle - locking in Oracle is more or less similar to locking in Postgres).

Comment: I would say faster execution critaria, as in the Pessimistic approach no deadlock happens but rows are kept locked during the whole transaction lifecycle.

And for the Optimistic Approach i just added a column about row version and testing against it each time i make an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Mssm can you please share how to incorporated the ORDER BY?